# want to use 2 class at once

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project in Java-Mail API, where I have a few fields and a button, when I click the button the mail will be sent. But the problem is I have a class that extend Fragment another class that extends Activity, and I don't know how to embed those two classes.

Here is the 1st class:

```
public class Contact_Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private Activity myActivity;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfragment_sendmail, container, false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

In `tabfragment_sendmail` I have a few fields and a button, I want to execute below class when the button is clicked.

```
public class OutsideClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Session session = null;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
    Context context = null;
    EditText reciep, sub, msg;
    String rec, subject, textMessage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        reciep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        sub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
        msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);

        login.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        rec = reciep.getText().toString();
        subject = sub.getText().toString();
        textMessage = msg.getText().toString();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxx@live.com", "xxxxxx");
            }
        });

        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail....", true);

        RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("rasem2009@live.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

                Transport.send(message);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {

            pdialog.dismiss();
            reciep.setText("");
            msg.setText("");
            sub.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is you dont know how to start another activity when your Button gets clicked?

You can do this like this

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent StartMyActivity = new Intent(this,Your_Activity.class);
     //Enter optional Intent.putExtras here
     start Activity(StartMyActivity);
 }
```

if u want to start from a non activity you need to replace "this" with a context
(I think `getApplicationContext()` should work? Havent tried that tough)

Comment: try to replace `this` with `getActivity();`

Comment: Thanks, it works,,,,the activity started.. though i got another error,, i hope i can fix that.....